# About floor level and height in SVF conversion of NWD file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Please let us know if you know.

I am having trouble getting the floor level and height when converting the NWD file to SVF.
If the RVT file is converted to SVF, the value can be obtained from the AEC data (the method below). Is there an alternative method?
"getDocumentNode().getAecModelData().levels"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right the feature of getAecModelData applies with Revit file only. If it is a Navisworks file, the level or room of Revit file has been extracted, and the [related information is attached as properties of the objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdRZn.jpg). So you could use Search method of Forge Viewer to get out all objects in one level, and get their merged bounding box, which can be the value for the range of a level.

If the browser nodes name have contained some keyword with 'level', you could simply get out those objects in one level by their names. Similarly, get their merged bounding box, which can be the value for the range of a level. One sample is produced by our team, which is based on such model. 
https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a7185a92a0a7aeb152725d5
The source code is available at [Level Extension of RCDB Sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/89e2e0af1d87e3b948cb66bc88f54140c6e8a0e8/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.LevelFilter/Viewing.Extension.LevelFilter.js). It can also be a reference for you on how to get merged boundingbox, and how to view the level by sectioning feature.